# d3 transform scale date to x position?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transformation

I have a linear y scale with a time series x scale. I want to put an overlay that follows the x/y value (similar to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569).

The issue is that I'm not able to transform to the proper x scale value; for example when I `mouseover` my chart it outputs (this data is correct):

```
{ y: 0.05, x: "2015-07-26 15:08:47" }
{ y: 0.05, x: "2015-07-26 15:08:47" }
{ y: 0.05, x: "2015-07-26 15:08:47" }
```

Now I want to use this data to draw a point at that location; the issue is that I cannot replicate the above bl.locks.org example, and the `transform` isn't able to use the x position as a date; so how can I transform that x date to the point on the chart?

My `mousemove` is below:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height,0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var varea = d3.svg.area()
    .defined(function(d) { return d.y != null; })
    .x(function(d) { return x(parseDate(d.x)); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

var svg = d3.select(".swatch").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseDate(d.x); }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    if (d.y >= 1) {
        return d.y
    }

    return 1;
})]);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", varea(data));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("display", "none");

focus.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5);

focus.append("text")
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        focus.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        focus.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
        var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);

        var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return parseDate(d.x); }).right;

        var item = data[bisect(data, x0)];

        focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(parseDate(item.x)) + "," + y(item.y) + ")");
        focus.select("text").text(item.y);

        console.log(x(parseDate(item.x)));
        console.log(y(item.y));
    });
```

This code produces errors like the following in the console:

```
Unexpected value translate(NaN,120) parsing transform attribute.
```

So, the question is how do I convert the date to a proper coordinate?

Comment: You're not using the result of your search for the nearest data point.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it should work. Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: So the problem is solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so there were a couple of problems with my code.

I wasn't parsing the `x` value as a date; so I started parsing it with `parseDate` (see sample code) and then passed it to the `x` scale; this allowed me to get proper location on the chart.

The second issue was that `display` wasn't be set properly (setting it to `null` in Firefox wasn't allowing it to appear). So I changed that to `display: inline;` and it started showing up on the chart.